# Custom Tabs shortcode

Tags: php, tabs, wordpress, shortcode

i'v spent a whole day trying to make a shortcode for the tabs that i made.I'v seen here a lot of codes, which i tried to add to functions.php but cant figure it out how to make it work for my case. Most of them are dynamical like tab 1, tab 2 and you add anything. But i want let's say 5 which would be always the same. So the titles would be the same and would have icon above it. This I would insert it inside wp posts. I'v made a nice style for it, and dont want to use plugin.

This is my html

```
<div class="tabs tabs-style-topline">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-1" class="icon icon-home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-2" class="icon icon-gift"><span>Deals</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-3" class="icon icon-upload"><span>Upload</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-4" class="icon icon-coffee"><span>Work</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#section-topline-5" class="icon icon-config"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <section id="section-topline-1"><p>1</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-2"><p>2</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-3"><p>3</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-4"><p>4</p></section>
                    <section id="section-topline-5"><p>5</p></section>
                </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /tabs -->
```

So any pointers, especially for function.php code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A shortcode, is a function that gets run when the code is inserted into the content of a post. The code is enclosed with square brackets like "[code-word]". So drop this in your functions.php file:

```
function my_tabs(){
     echo ("Hello world!");
}
add_shortcode( 'my_tabs', 'my_tabs' );
```

Then add the text "[my_tabs]" to any post to display "Hello world!". Change "Hello world!" to anything you want.

Comment: I think i described my situation wrong. Tabs title with icons would be the same, but the content below would be changed. On this way that you suggested i could add the whole part which wont be changed anytime and while this is true for the top part, how would i do it, so i can output "content" part dynamically so i can change it for any post i want?